# How to handle a relationship for only non-zero values of dependent variables in linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, nonlinear-regression

I have a dependent variable in my model which is non-zero only for part of all observations. The example dataset could look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(0, 10), 
                       runif(12, 0, 2000), 
                       rep(0, 8), 
                       runif(14, 0, 2000), 
                       rep(0, 23), 
                       runif(33, 0, 2000))) %>% 
  mutate(y = exp(x / 1000) + rnorm(100, 0, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(x == 0, runif(100, 0, 10), y))

df %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y))
```

[image]

So as you can see, there is a visible relationship for non-zero values of `x` and `y`, but if `x == 0` the values of response variable are still varied. It's quite obvious that the problem occurs due to omitted variable bias and although I have other dependent variables to feed into my model, they can't really capture all the points of interest. I know that one way would be to limit my dataset to only those observations for which `x > 0`, however it's unfortunetely not an option for me. So I wanted to ask how can I handle such a relationship in multivariable linear regression so I could fit a non-linear function to x (probably exponens in the case shown)? I was thinking about something like creating a dummy variable that would indicate if `x > 0` and potentially capture a little bit of variance from `x == 0` by predicting the mean of all those points. However, I'm not really sure if that's a valid approach and was thinking about possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably fit this with a model that looks like this:

$$E[y \vert x]= \alpha+\beta \cdot I(x>0) + \gamma \cdot x \cdot I(x>0)+ \delta \cdot x^2 \cdot I(x>0), $$

where $I()=1$ if $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise.

There is probably a more elegant way to do this in R, but this should do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(0, 10), 
                       runif(12, 0, 2000), 
                       rep(0, 8), 
                       runif(14, 0, 2000), 
                       rep(0, 23), 
                       runif(33, 0, 2000))) %>% 
  mutate(y = exp(x / 1000) + rnorm(100, 0, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(x == 0, runif(100, 0, 10), y))

df$pos_x <- ifelse(df$x >0 , 1, 0)
ols<-lm(y~pos_x + pos_x:I(x) + pos_x:I(x^2),data=df)

df %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +    
  geom_point(aes(x,predict(ols), color='red'))
```

The predictions from the model are shown in red:

[image]

Comment: @Xaume Did this clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in many data-sets. Look into zero-inflated models and hurdle models. Depending on the specifics of your variables, a version of one of those should be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don’t think this is zero-inflated. That would be if, no matter the predictor, the response has a large amount of 0s.