# Alternative for transformation of predictors

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

[image]I am working with multiple linear regression models and am attempting to transform the predictors of the model. I am attempting to use the powertransform() function however since my data contains zeros, doing so returns an error stating that the first value must be strictly postive. Is there an alternative to the powertransform function when data contains zeros?  The data looks as below. I would like to transform it in order to get a better linear regression model

Comment: What does your data look like/ represent? Why do you want to transform it? Can you show examples\histograms?

Comment: Hi I posted a capture of the data set

Comment: What exactly does "better" LRM mean? That's sort of like saying you want a better pair of shoes. Without specifying what you seek to accomplish, we can't steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov my model when plotting the residuals vs fitted and the residual vs predictors saw discreptancies like clustering, non constant variance stc; I have already transformed the response which led to improvements but not as great as wanted.

Comment: One approach is to use theory/local knowledge to inform how predictors should be transformed. One approach might be to bin them into 0, 1-3, 4-5, or something else meaningful, and then use dummies. You often get good ideas here by plotting the data and doing some thinking about the science of the problem. You have not specified the outcome and your goal, so it is hard to offer more concrete guidance.

Comment: Another approach would be to replace the zeros with a small positive number and then do the transform. This is less demanding on you, but a bit ad hoc, and the results can be sensitive to what that small number is.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov my only goal is really to provide a good model for the data, not much else.

Comment: Instead of some arbitrary transformations, I suggest you fit a Generalized Additive Model (see R package mgcv). Then you can inspect the smoothers and, if you need a parametric model, you can then still look for transformations that result in the same shape. If your goal is prediction, you can just use machine learning approaches (which sort of would also include GAMs).

Comment: A third approach would be something like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/466615/7071).

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I think I will attempt the last suggested approach. Thank you.

Comment: What is the goal of your undertaking? Unless this is a homework problem or a kaggle competition "getting the best fit " is hardly the actual goal of what you try to accomplish - if yes let machines do this, they are (by now) better than humans at this and cheaper/faster as well.  What question are you trying to answer? A prediction problem, an inference problem, a causal problem,....?

Comment: The data screenshot doesn't really tell us what is uour y and x variables

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg I am simply trying to fit a linear regression model with compressive strength as the response variable.

Comment: How was the data collected? Are the 0s in there structural or missing indicators, ie. Did you deliberably not add a particular component at all for a particular row? These are actually continuous variables yet they show many exact zeros , which is odd to occur naturally.  No continuous transform won't make this discontinuity go away.  I suggest adding indicator variables for component ==0 instead.  Also can you show histograms of response and an example predictor

Comment: Again, fitting a linear regression is rarely a goal of its own.  I m sure you are trying to do sthg with that regression. Depending on what you want to do, getting "the best fit" might not be the best solution. It can also hurt you (e.g. if you want to know the effect of component x on the outcome (compressive strength) - ie causal inference - getting "the best fit" is not necessarily giving you the best (unbiased/least variance ) amswer

Answer (score 1):

Well one way is to just add one to every value and then transform, Powertransform$(x+1)$. I assume this is some type of Box-Cox transform.

But, looking at your picture it looks like a very large number of the entries are zero. If virtually every value is zero, there is not much information that the column can provide, so it might be better to drop the column and create a model using the other columns.

If there are a few but a nontrial number of non-zero values, it might also be good to make all the non-zero values one and make the column a categorical variable with two levels, zero and one. Here you are just trying to detect the situation that would make it non-zero.

If there are a reasonable number of non-zero values, but the distribution of the column is non-normal, you can make it zero-one as above, or bin the predictor into some reasonable number of levels, or standardize the column, ie subtract the mean and divide by the sd.

It should be noted that the requirement of linear regression is not normal predictors OR normal response, rather, normal residuals after the regression model has been fit.

There are possibly other things I can't think of off the top of my head right now.

Comment: The general aim of my analysis is simply to provide the best model I can. Do you think that setting the zeros say equal to .1 would provide much of a difference in values for coefficients?

Comment: The problem isn't exactly that they are mostly all zero, it is that they are all the same value. Setting them all to .1 doesn't fix the problem. How many zeros and non-zeros for the relevant columns?

Comment: There are a great deal that are zeros, in every single column, the dataset pretty much sought to isolate factors and exluded others hence the zeros.

Comment: it seems that this might be the solution, wil; the result that follows after adding one to the numbers be accurate ? Note: I have checked for normality of residuals and found that normality.

Comment: Adding one to all the values and then transforming will bias the results. If you ran the model with all the values as numeric and the residuals are normal, and all the other linear regression checks are good too, your model is good!

Comment: I wanted to fix the above but it wouldn't let me. I wanted to say that you should run the model with no transformations and then check the residuals. If they're good, the model's assumptions are met, and that is the model you should "go with."